# How can I merge data into an XDP file and return a PDF (via .NET)?

Tags: .net, serialization, livecycle

My team has a template (XDP) that we've created with the Adobe LiveCycle designer.

The situation:

- We are replacing an old Acrobat form
  (XFDF format) with this LiveCycle
  form as part of a much larger upgrade
- The current Acrobat form is
  dynamically populated with basic data
  and delivered to the user as a PDF
  (the user clicks a link and a PDF
  opens on their machine pre-populated
  with basic demographic details)
- The current process looks something like: user clicks, .NET app retrieves data, .NET app retrieves PDF from file system, .NET app serializes data into template in XFDF form, ASP.NET app sends an HTTP response back to the user in XFDF format, the user views the PDF in Adobe Reader

We would like to maintain a roughly analogous process with the new XDP format.

For the record, we *DO* have access to the LiveCycle services that do this type of work (e.g. the Render service).  That said, we would like to create this type of serialization in .NET for a few reasons: we have limited LiveCycle licenses and will struggle to access the LiveCycle services due to their location in the enterprise.

Any thoughts (even "stop doing that, you're insane") are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, sorry for the slow reply, didn't see this.

Create the PDF.  Encode it as base64.

Create a text file, foo.xdp:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xfa generator='AdobeDesigner_V7.0' APIVersion='2.2.4333.0'?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp='http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/'>
    <xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa='http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/'>
        <xfa:data>
```

Insert the XML here that is your dynamic data, matching the dynamic fields in the PDF.

```
        </xfa:data>
    </xfa:datasets>
    <pdf xmlns=\"http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/pdf/\"><document>
       <chunk>
```

Without putting any characters after the  tag, insert the base64 encoded PDF.

```
        </chunk>
    </document></pdf>
</xdp:xdp>
```

And, lo and behold, you have a valid XDP.  Adobe Reader will accept this and display the PDF with your values in it.

In Java, if you have a Properties with the connection details in it, the following code can use Livecycle to turn an XDP to a PDF, although your mileage might vary in C#.

```
        // Create a ServiceClientFactory object
        ServiceClientFactory myFactory = ServiceClientFactory
                .createInstance(connectionProperties);

        // Create a PDF Utility client
        PDFUtilityServiceClient pdfClient = new PDFUtilityServiceClient(myFactory);

        // Specify an XDP file to convert to a PDF document
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(xdp.getBytes("ASCII"));
        Document inDoc = new Document(bais);

        // Convert the XDP file to a PDF document
        Document pdf = pdfClient.convertXDPtoPDF(inDoc);

        // Return the PDF as an InputStream.
        return pdf.getInputStream();
```

Comment: This is great. It works fine, I manage to do the same thing in ColdFusion.

Comment: great! One thing I need to know is if it is possible to convert XDP to PDF using some open source utility ? And it would be great if it can be done via Python or Node.js.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I try with Adobe LiveCycle Designer 11.  Does anyone know how to create this with LiveCycle 11. I the following error after creating the XDP file and trying to open it. Adobe Reader could not open 'sample-order-form.pdf' because it has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasnt correctly decoded)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for client-side rendering - something that I've never really been able to use in a workable fashion. And given that you're working in .Net it'll probably make things impossible..

In my opinion your best bet will definitely be to use the render service that comes with Forms ES. Probably doesn't help much, but hey :)

Comment: I dont think so Greg. Acrobat Reader is capable of rending XDP files.