# Filling an existing dynamic and complex PDF form from Website

Tags: php, pdf, libraries, dynamically-generated, livecycle

I have seen a lot of questions regarding PDF's forms filled from a Website by using several PDF libraries but I can't find an straight answer to my concern. I have a very complex PDF that somebody built with LiveCycle, which includes things like buttons for dynamic addition of rows in tables.
I wonder if it is possible to fill this form from a Website's form or a DDBB, and if there is any library that can achieve things like adding the extra rows to the table and/or to peep inside the internal PDF's javascript to understand it's logic.
Adobe LiveCycle is not even an option, as their server solutions' prices, are far out of the mortals' reach.
Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Everything that is entered into the form ends up in an XML data structure embedded within the form. My idea is to create a pre-filled data structure using that website of yours and see if you can "inject" it into the form. I'm gonna try a proof-of-concept if I can find some time this weekend.

Comment: Hello Basim, after some experiments I have found that the only thing you need is to modify the XFA lines inside the XDP file which is contained inside the PDF (when it is a LiveCycle generated one) and everything will work. What I wonder now and I will make a new question  if I don't find a similar one here is: can I get the XDP file from a PDF with a PHP script?

Comment: I don't know – maybe there is a PHP PDF library that'll do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments I have found that the only thing you need is to modify the XFA lines inside the XDP file which is contained inside the PDF (when it is a LiveCycle generated one) and everything will work.
An explanation can be found in here:
[How can I merge data into an XDP file and return a PDF (via .NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757397/how-can-i-merge-data-into-an-xdp-file-and-return-a-pdf-via-net)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you hand write a parser (which is quite a feat..) but it's extremely difficult. It would probably be easiest to simply generate a new pdf with the needed information stored as static text.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to generate a new PDF, as this PDF is somehow a legal document to be returned exactly as it is.